# iframe will not display ms chart in webpage

Tags: asp.net, iframe, mschart

I am trying to display a webpage with a MS chart control. The entire page displays excpept for the MS chart control. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on the server?  If you load the page outside of an iframe, does the chart show?

Comment: If i put the url in a link label or paste url in address bar it renders perfect. Didn't notice any errors on server.

Comment: After investiagion, when i right click the area of the chart control and go to properties, i then paste the that url in address bar and get "404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." this only happens with an IFrame though.

Comment: I answered my own question. All I had to do was publish the app to the server were the chartcontrol web app was located and then it worked just fine.